# Amazon AWS s3 upload using image content - PHP

Tags: php

I am using the following code to upload image to the `ECS server`. Here I am first storing the image first to a temporary location and then uploading that to the server.

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
                   'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
                'SourceFile' => $temp,
                    'Key'    => $Destination_folder,
                    'ACL'    => 'public-read',
                    'ContentType' => 'text/plain',
                    'Expires' => $expire
                     ));
```

I want to remove the use of this temporary location. So is there any way to upload image directly using the image content only.

Comment: you can check the API here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using 'Body' of s3 putObject for image content.

```
 $result = $s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
            'Key'    => $Destination_folder,
            'Body'   => $image_content 
            ));
```

Comment: This would upload a file with content-type: string. It won't upload an image correctly, one needs to also set the content-type.

Comment: Yes setting content-type will be fine and if he is giving the file name with proper image extension then even this will work with decoded image content.